# ¿Como mostrar los datos en la vista desde una consulta groupBy() Laravel?

Tags: laravel

tengo una vista donde quisiera mostrar los datos en forma correcta tras hacer en el controlador la consulta groupBy().

En el controlador tengo:

```
 $pormesYanios = Formulari::orderBy('created_at')->get()->groupBy(function($item) {
        return $item->created_at->format('Y-m');
    });
```

Y en la vista:

```
  <div id="accordion">

                        @foreach($pormesYanios as $porfecha)
                            <h2>TITULO</h2>
                            <div style="max-height: 300px;">
                                <h4><span style="color:red;">FECHA:</span> <br> {{$porfecha}}</h4>
                            </div>

                        @endforeach
                    </div>
```

Queda ordenado como quiero, pero me muestra los datos de esta forma:
[{"id":32,"sms_required":0,"display":10,"category":0,"segment1":16777215,"segment2":511,"segment3":7,"created_at":"2018-03-09 12:14:15","updated_at":"2018-05-07 13:02:28","title":"HOJA DE MODIFICACI\u00d3N DATOS PERSONALES","description":"--"}]

No se como hacer para mostrar solo los datos que me interesan y de forma correcta, como por ejemplo, dentro de una tabla.

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score -1):

Para sacar el titulo lo que tienes que hacer es poner

```
$porfecha->elnombredelcampoquequieres
```

y con eso ya esta

Comment: Hola harman, ya probé esto, pero me sale el siguiente error:

Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance.